# Adjust Flipclock.js labels

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I would like to have the labels (Days, Hours, Min..) be below the actual countdown.

Currently, I am doing the following to render the countdown. I was not able to find any documentation on how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var date = new Date("August 12, 2020 02:15:00"); //Month Days, Year HH:MM:SS
var now = new Date();
var diff = (date.getTime()/1000) - (now.getTime()/1000);

var clock;
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(
    diff, {
        countdown: true,
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        callbacks: {
        stop: function () {
          /**/
        }
    }
});
```